# Four partitions cannot be found ubuntu

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have run into a significant problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop machine. I rebooted my computer to implement some updates, and ran into my `/tmp`, `/home`, `/var`, and `/srv` partitions not being located:

```
The disk drive for ____ is not ready yet or not present. 
keys:Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

From my search on the internet it seems there is something wrong with my `/etc/fstab` file, but I have no idea how to correct it.  Any ideas? I am reasonably proficient with unix/linux terminal commands.
Thanks.

`lsblk -f` result:

```
NAME    FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda
|-sda1                    /boot
|-sda2
    |-ARG.OS-ROOT (dm-0)  /`
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=917eab46-885a-4a17-baa2-8198524d3df5    /        ext4   default\s,errors=remount-ro    0    1
UUID=b1940634-6f59-44cb-93e9-be72f1ce5b23    /boot        ext4    default\s    0    2
UUID=cc6f48fe-e59a-41df-bf6a-74fef2499d3b    /var         ext4    default\s    0    2
UUID=482bb4c8-b146-40f9-8d7f-9d17d5b7cbac    /tmp         ext4    default\s    0    2
UUID=b4c47fe2-dad9-4d84-9fc2-ac4f334e7535    /home        ext4    default\s    0    2
UUID=dbb1c6c0-aff5-4a86-9b78-3db4b25b078e    /srv         ext4    default\s    0    2
```

Note these are on the same physical drive, and is not hardware issue

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `/etc/fstab` file and the output of `lsblk -f`, please? Don't know if you get access to a (root) shell when you hit `M` at that prompt. Maybe you need the rescue option from the GRUB menu if you can't get a shell otherwise.

Comment: Please don't attempt to post command outputs in comments, they will lose their formatting and become barely readable. Also, comments might get removed without warning for various reasons. Please [edit] your question to add the output. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not redact the UUIDs of drives from the output. They are not sensitive information and might be useful to diagnose the problem if some of them appear in different error messages.

Comment: Sorry. I the issue was I have to transcribe everything by hand, and since you have so nicely stopped by to help, I wanted to get the info up asap. Hopefully that is all correct.

Comment: Since the issue appears to be that it can not find the partitions, should I try some type of disk recovery, or pulling out a backup, and reinstall ubuntu?